# PHP : Difference of $_ENV and $GLOBALS

Tags: php

What is the difference of using `$_ENV` and `$GLOBALS` ?

I wish to have a global variable to get and set at anytime and anywhere (need to be accessible in OO class & plain procedural PHP script). Which of the above should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use global variables at all and instead use dependency injection (i.e. pass all necessary data as function parameters), but if you have to, use `$GLOBALS`. `$_ENV` holds data from outside the PHP script passed by the system. While it may serve the purpose as a superglobal, that's not what it's meant for.

Comment: so the answer is to go for `$GLOBALS`. Will the variable value be dismissed after the PHP script ended execution?

Comment: Yes. It's not persistent, it's just global.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) as that is the purpose it was made for, to provide a place to set global variables that can be accessed in any context of your PHP code (inside function, classes, anywhere).

But as a good programming practice don't abuse global vars, in contrast try that your functions and objects methods have in context all data they need to work it, so your code is more flexible, see [globals are evil](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aGlobals_are_evil).

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative to globals, take a look at how Zend does this. Zend registry: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.html

Basically it is a class with some static methods for getting and setting variables.

I personally prefer this kind of approach to using globals.

Comment: It's basically the same thing though, just wrapped in a class. Still not a practice you should overuse.

Comment: Yes, it is basically the same thing, and agreed it's not something you want to overuse. The reason I prefer the Zend approach is that it can be easily extended. For example you might want to make some variables read-only. As I said, it's just an alternative, and a personal preference.